# Problemas al ejecutar comando ipconfig desde VBScript

Tags: cmd, vbscript

Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar ejecutar un comando desde **VBScript** que funciona correctamente desde linea de comandos.

Desde **CMD** ejecuto con éxito:

> ipconfig /all | find /i "Servidor DHCP"

Pero desde **VBScript** si ejecuto lo siguiente:

```js
Dim vIpConfig
vIpConfig = oShell.Exec("ipconfig /all | find /i ""Servidor DHCP""").StdOut.ReadAll

MsgBox(vIpConfig)
```

El *MsgBox* me devuelve el error:

> Error: línea de comando desconocida o incompleta.

Es decir, el comando llega pero algo en la sintaxis está incorrecto y no me doy cuenta que es. Creo estar escapando las comillas correctamente.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: intenta asi con comillas simple vIpConfig = oShell.Exec('ipconfig /all | find /i ""Servidor DHCP" ').StdOut.ReadAll

Comment: En VBScript las comillas simples son para comentar código. No se puede hacer de esa manera. Igualmente gracias por tu respuesta : ).

Answer (score 0):

al paraser el caracter | or Chr(124) or hex 7C lo ve como algo mas pero puedes intentar asi y el resultado es igual:

```
Dim vIpConfig
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
vIpConfig = oShell.Exec("ipconfig /all").StdOut.ReadAll
MsgBox(InStr(vIpConfig,"Servidor DHCP"))
```